# why is my grappling hook pushing me when i flip the character in godot

Tags: 2d, godot

When i flip the character and use the grappling hook it pushes me away from the grappling hook and not toward.

player.gd

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const JUMP_FORCE = 1540         # Force applied on jumping
const MOVE_SPEED = 500          # Speed to walk with
const GRAVITY = 60              # Gravity applied every second
const MAX_SPEED = 2000          # Maximum speed the player is allowed to move
const FRICTION_AIR = 1      # The friction while airborne
const FRICTION_GROUND = 0.85    # The friction while on the ground
const CHAIN_PULL = 130


var velocity = Vector2(0,0)     # The velocity of the player (kept over time)
var chain_velocity := Vector2(0,0)
var can_jump = false            # Whether the player used their air-jump





func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.pressed:
            # We clicked the mouse -> shoot()
            $Chain.shoot(event.position - get_viewport().size * 0.5)
        else:
            # We released the mouse -> release()
            $Chain.release()
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        print("Mouse Click/Unclick at: ", event.position)   

# This function is called every physics frame
func _physics_process(_delta: float) -> void:
    
    var local_mouse_pos = get_local_mouse_position()
    if (local_mouse_pos.x < 0):
        scale.x = -30
        
    else:
        scale.x = 30

    
    # Walking
    var walk = (Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")) * MOVE_SPEED
    
    #talking
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action") and $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
        print("wow")
        transform.get_origin()
    

    
        
    # Falling
    velocity.y += GRAVITY

    # Hook physics
    if $Chain.hooked:
        # `to_local($Chain.tip).normalized()` is the direction that the chain is pulling
        chain_velocity = to_local($Chain.tip).normalized() * CHAIN_PULL
        if chain_velocity.y > 0:
            # Pulling down isn't as strong
            chain_velocity.y *= 0.30
        else:
            # Pulling up is stronger
            chain_velocity.y *= 0.60
        if sign(chain_velocity.x) != sign(walk):
            # if we are trying to walk in a different
            # direction than the chain is pulling
            # reduce its pull
            chain_velocity.x *= 0.7
    else:
        # Not hooked -> no chain velocity
        chain_velocity = Vector2(0,0)
    velocity += chain_velocity

    velocity.x += walk      # apply the walking
    move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)    # Actually apply all the forces
    velocity.x -= walk      # take away the walk speed again
    # ^ This is done so we don't build up walk speed over time

    # Manage friction and refresh jump and stuff
    velocity.y = clamp(velocity.y, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)   # Make sure we are in our limits
    velocity.x = clamp(velocity.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    var grounded = is_on_floor()
    if grounded:
        velocity.x *= FRICTION_GROUND   # Apply friction only on x (we are not moving on y anyway)
        can_jump = true                 # We refresh our air-jump
        if velocity.y >= 5:     # Keep the y-velocity small such that
            velocity.y = 5      # gravity doesn't make this number huge
    elif is_on_ceiling() and velocity.y <= -5:  # Same on ceilings
        velocity.y = -5

    # Apply air friction
    if !grounded:
        velocity.x *= FRICTION_AIR
        if velocity.y > 0:
            velocity.y *= FRICTION_AIR

    # Jumping
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        if grounded:
            velocity.y = -JUMP_FORCE    # Apply the jump-force
        elif can_jump:
            can_jump = false    # Used air-jump
            velocity.y = -JUMP_FORCE
```

Comment: I don't know. Is `$Chain.tip` global? Because I'm thinking `$Chain.tip` is local to `$Chain`, then you would need `to_local($Chain.to_global($Chain.tip))`. The other thing that worries me is the use `scale` (edit: that can mess with physics, so avoid doing that on physics objects. I guess you need to transform the children instead).

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: Now it does not work. It brings me up now but in the opposite direction.Last time I used it it worked right now it does not.